# Azure node.js app - override SQL Server port 5984

Tags: sql-server, node.js, azure

Azure seems to be overriding my SQL Server port..

I have it configured for port 1433 and it works perfectly locally but on Azure it's replacing the port with 5984.. resulting in connection timeouts.

I'm using the NPM module `mssql`

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you please edit your question to clarify? Are you running SQL Server in a VM and having trouble configuring that? Did you push a node app to an Azure Web App (website)? Is your node app attempting connect to port 5984?

Comment: According to your question, we can know little for troubleshooting. It will be great if you can supply for info. Beside @David Makogon said, it's better if you can post your code snippet of mssql connection.

Answer (score 0):

I build an Express application with a request function for Azure SQL test connection on Azure Web Apps, it works fine on my side. As by default, the nodejs mssql module has set port to 1433, and to connect to Azure SQL server, there is   not a necessary to set port in configurations.

Azure will not change the code we deploy on Azure Web Apps. I think you need to check your code whether there are anything like misconfigurations or conflictions.

Here is my test connection function for you information.

```
app.get('/mssql',function(req,res){
    var sql = require('mssql');
    var config = {
        user: 'username',
        password: 'password',
        server: '{servername}.database.windows.net', // You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance 
        database: '{database name}',
        port:1433,
        options: {
            encrypt: true // Use this if you're on Windows Azure 
        }
    }

    var connection = new sql.Connection(config, function(err) {
        // ... error checks 

        // Query 

        var request = new sql.Request(connection); // or: var request = connection.request(); 
        request.query('select 1 as number', function(err, recordset) {
            // ... error checks 

            res.send(recordset);
        });

    });

    connection.on('error', function(err) {
        // ... error handler 
    });
})
```

On the other hand, if your SQL server database is on an Azure VM, you can directly configure the port in **ENDPOINT** tab of your VM portal site. You can customize the private port to public port.